# Meteor.error/ throw not displaying from server in Safari or Firefox

Tags: meteor

Right now, for no apparent reason I can not get throw new Meteor.Error(etc, etc) to throw from the server in a methods method and populate into the callback in Safari and Firefox. It does however appear to work almost everytime for Chrome. I can get some code samples when the form seems to be up again.

server/signup.js

```
Meteor.methods({
  createCustomer: function(email, card) {
    console.log('server');
    if (!email || !card) {
      throw new Meteor.Error('missing fields');
    }
return {
  id: 1,
  email: email,
  card: card
 };
  },
createCustomerSubscription: function(custId, plan) {
return {
  plan: {
    customerId: custId,
    name: plan
    }
   };
  }
 });
```

client/signup.js

```
Meteor.call('createCustomer', customer, function(error, response) {
  if (error) {
    return console.log(error);
  } else {
    return console.log(response);
  }
});
```

I am seeing the console log for the that says server, in the terminal, but do not see any browser console logs in Safari or Firefox, yet I do in Chrome.

Comment: That is a bit odd. What happens if you omit the return in the callback - doing console.log(error) instead of return console.log(error)?

Answer (score 0):

Aw shucks...found the issue. Appears it was waiting on a sub from SubsManager in the router configure block, which was blocking the error to be thrown back to the client...quite the rabbit hole to find the issue.